# Multiple Asynchronous Operations in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

In one Angular Component I'm dealing with three or four Observables.
I need to refactor this some way in order to avoid this poorly written code with ugly nested subscribe calls.
It's important as you can see that productService should be called before queryParamMap, while call to categoryService isn't crucial.

I tried to refactor this with forkJoin and switchMap but without success.

```
this.productService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        (products: any) => {
          this.products = products;
          this.categoryService.getAll()
            .subscribe(categories => this.categories = categories);
          this.route.queryParamMap
            .subscribe(params => {
              this.category = params.get('category');

              if (this.category) {
                this.productService.getProductsByCategory(this.category)
                  .subscribe(fProducts => this.filteredProducts = fProducts);
              } else {
                this.filteredProducts = this.products;
              }
            },
              err => {
                console.log(err);
              }
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your code like this

```
this.productService.getAll()
.pipe(
    switchMap(products => {
        this.products = products;
        return this.categoryService.getAll()
            .pipe(
                map(categories => this.categories = categories)
            );
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.route.queryParamMap
        .pipe(
            switchMap(params => {
                this.category = params.get('category');
                return defer(() =>
                    (Boolean(this.category) ?
                     this.productService.getProductsByCategory(this.category) :
                     of(this.products)
                    )
                );
            })
        )
    )
)
.subscribe((filteredProducts) => {
        this.filteredProducts = filteredProducts;
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using *forkJoin* and *switchMap* is "right" approach and strange that it didn't work. Here is how I see it could be refactored.

```
forkJoin([
  this.productService.getAll(),
  this.categoryService.getAll()
])
.pipe(
  switchMap(([products, categories]) => {
    this.products = products;
    this.categories = categories;
    return this.route.queryParamMap;
  }),
  switchMap((params) => {
    this.category = params.get('category');
    return this.category ? this.productService.getProductsByCategory(this.category) : of(this.products);
  }),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$) // or take(1)
)
.subscribe((filteredProducts) => {
        this.filteredProducts = filteredProducts;
    },
    err => {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```